# Storing variable passed from node server to EJS file as input data for form

Tags: javascript, electron, ejs

I'm trying to store a variable called from the server as the default value of a form. The for loop I used is correctly displaying all the data and even calling the data directly inside a paragraph is displaying the data. But I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined". All of this is in an .ejs file.

```html
<body onload="getEmail()">

  // Testing retrieving email - Works
    <p><%= garage[0].email %></p>

  // Function and Form to plugin email into form - Failing on undefined email
    <script>
     function getEmail() {
        var email = <%= garage[0].email %>;
        document.getElementById('myemail').value = email;
     }
    </script>


      <div class="form">
        <form action="http://ec2-52-23-218-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/admingarage" method="post">
          <input class="input" data-name="uname" id="myemail" maxlength="256" name="uname" type="email">
          <input class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" data-wait="Please wait..." type="submit" name="action"><i class="material-icons">replay</i></input>
        </form>
      </div>


    // Displaying Garage - Works
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="garage">
            <% for(var i=0; i < garage.length; i++) {%>
                <div class="col s2">
                  <div class="card blue-grey">
                      <div class="card-content white-text">
                          <span class="card-title">Car <%= i + 1 %></span>
                          <p><span><b>Year: </b><%= garage[i].year %></span></p>
                          <p><span><b>Make: </b><%= garage[i].make %></span></p>
                          <p><span><b>Model: </b><%= garage[i].model %></span></p>
                          <p><span><b>Exterior: </b><%= garage[i].exterior %></span></p>
                          <p><span><b>Interior: </b> <%= garage[i].interior %></span></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
      </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Try `var email = garage[0].email;`

Comment: But why not insert the email directly into the `<input>`?

Comment: Hi.I have a problem with sending data from server into template. Can you provide me server side code ?. I cant send a data to template.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
document.getElementById('myemail').value = <%- JSON.stringify(garage[0].email) %>;
```